# Different forms of Stirling numbers of second type formula

Tags: stirling-numbers, set-partition

The number of partitions of a set with $m$ elements into $n$ nonempty subsets is given by the Stirling numbers of the second type, $S(m,n)$. The formula to find $S(m,n)$ is said to be:

> $$
> S(m,n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
> $$

But at some places it is given as:

> $$
> S(m,n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^m
> $$

How do I go to the second formula from the first one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can go from one formula to the other by reverting the order of summation $k\rightarrow n-k$. In general we have by switching the summation order this way:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^na_k =\sum_{k=0}^na_{n-k}
\end{align*}

> Here we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{n!}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{n-k}(n-(n-k))^m\tag{$k\rightarrow n-k$}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^m}\\
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Unless i'm confused, this comes directly from symmetry of binomial expansion. You can notice the symmetry by letting n=2, n=3 etc

Comment: there is no need for an inductive step, its literally just $k \mapsto n-k$

Comment: Yeah, i just wrote it in case he's not aware of the symmetry of binomial expansion, so he can notice it too

Comment: @dankmemer I understand the symmetry u mentioned, ie. $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.  The second equation seems like just replacing $k$ by $n-k$ in the first equation. But how do i mathematically prove it ?

Comment: I'm too lazy to write it explicity, but if the binomial expression is $a_{1} + a_{2} + ... + a_{n}$ then writing this as $a_{n} + a_{n-1} + ... + a_{1}$ will give you the same thing, that's what i meant by the symmetry also this is the reason why the equation you gave holds.